# Is this number rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the following number:

$x=0.01001000100001...$

(the number of '$0$' between '$1$'s increases linearly)

given by the sum

$$x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty 10^{-i - i (1 + i)/2}$$

My question is whether this number (or more generally, numbers generated by this technique), are rational or irrational, and what is the sketch of proof.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A number given in decimal (or any $n$-ary representation other than $n=1$) is rational if, and only if, its representation contains a block that from some point onwards repeats indefinitely. The number you describe clearly can't contain any such repeating block, so it is irrational.

Comment: by the same argument it is also clearly a non-normal number

Comment: By this argument too: it doesn't contain the finite sequence "2" (nor the sequence "11").

Comment: I think it would be useful to prove the first statement of this solution. Concerning the "only if" clause, [you can prove that the decimal expansion of rational numbers is eventually periodic via the Pigeonhole Principle](http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/decimal.pdf). You could prove the "if" clause with continued fractions, but perhaps there is a better method.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps it could be mentioned that if you space out more drastically your ones
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 10^{- i!}
$$
you get [Liouville's number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html) which is *transcendental* over the rationals.

Comment: Damn! I've been boasting at many a place (in www and at a few bars) that I have memorized Liouville's number to 1 million decimal places. Now you blew my cover! (+1)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen :-)

Comment: Not sure why this is considered helpful, understanding why Liouville's number is transcendental is a world away from proving that rational number have repeating (or terminating) decimal representations. Interesting is not a substitute for relevant.